# Anyone know why the word "Start" is always clipped with ellipsis in DSL?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, dsl

Where ever I use the word "Start" it ends up looking like "St...", this is within my dsl, and within the main dsl.  The decorator is defined on a base shape and shared, so width and stuff shouldn't play a part.

Anyone know why this is?

I mean I could just change it to "Begin" or "Initiate", but really?

This is in my design:

[image: huh?]

Below:
If you look here the top St... is a decorator showing the domain property for Type name and bottom one is actually the name domain property, both are "Start".

[image: huh?]

Comment: Could you try to create a step-by-step guide to recreating this issue and include it in your question? Start with Visual Studio open and the New Project Wizard open. For starters, I've no idea in what *context* you're using the word Start and then in what context you're *viewing* it, such that you're observing this behaviour.

Comment: When I use it either as a domain class name when defining my dsl or as domain property value within my dsl.  I've included screenshots above, and I'll expand on my description above

Comment: Just added a new Domain Class to a toy language project of mine and renamed it `Start` and I'm seeing no ellipses. Time to start the (probably long) process of elimination by removing extensions/tools, etc and see if any of them are causing this.

Comment: Thanks for the response...not the answer I was looking for, but thanks anyway ;), and since this isn't production code and just POC I'll let it slide for now and put some more time into it if I get the go ahead to continue with this project. But thanks though for the response.